# Generalization of Jordan Curve To possibly self-intersecting loops

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $\gamma$ be a closed loop in the sphere $S^2$, with possibly self intersections. Is it true that every component of $S^2\backslash \gamma$ is simply connected?

Comment: This is true for any connected closed subset of $S^2$, not just the image of a loop.